# If the hamburger is dead, how do I change Bootstrap 3 to use another symbol/icon?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, hamburger-menu

I guess the title says it all. I keep reading how the hamburger menu (the three lines that appear on a minimized menu) is so passe, but can anybody show me a way I can change the three lines to perhaps another shape, maybe chevrons perhaps?

Comment: The hamburger isn't "dead" because of an issue with the icon, it's dead (arguably) because the concept is dead. So I don't think this is the right question to ask.

Comment: so bootstrap's collapsible navigation system concept is "dead" arguably? I saw that some were replacing text navigation with icons, and I've done that in the past with simple navigation, is that the way forward?

Comment: "Arguably" being key :) According to the Bootstrap v4 Alpha documentation - http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/ - the collapsible navigation is still available, and the example uses a Unicode-based hamburger. On the other hand, it's hip to complain about the _hamburger menu mechanic_ (nobody is upset about the specific icon). Therefore I maintain that changing just the icon doesn't help anything, and actually stands to hurt, since now the hamburger is what users are accustomed to.

Comment: I find this thread pretty interesting, dead by who's standards, developers? I think the average internet user would find the hamburger menu and the vanilla icon to be sufficiently modern and intuitive for a website in 2016 (and imo through 2020+). I could easily be wrong about this though, I tend to like traditional styles : ' )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the icon by replacing this:

```
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

With something like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
```

Here's a fiddle showing this:

http://jsfiddle.net/edencorbin/gkssyqy9/

Comment: excellent, thank you! That was just what I was looking for! It is a way to freshen up the old style three lines, but not make sweeping design concept changes to collapsible navbars just yet :) Thank you!

Comment: You can also easily change the icons based on if the menu is closed or open, here's an example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/6u5kohh0/3/